# Makefile generator specification at cross compilation with CMake

Tags: makefile, cmake, raspberry-pi

I have two things I can't figure out.
(1)When using `CMake-GUI`, we can specify makefile generator. I am going to cross compile for Raspberry PI with Debian Linux. I can't find the relevant generator. Which generator I have to choose?
I have `toolchain-rpi.cmake` as follow.

```
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux) # this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)  # this one not so much

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   $ENV{RPI_CC}/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER $ENV{RPI_CC}/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-g++)
SET(CMAKE_AR           $ENV{RPI_CC}/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-ar)
SET(CMAKE_LINKER       $ENV{RPI_CC}/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-ld)
SET(CMAKE_NM           $ENV{RPI_CC}/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-nm)
SET(CMAKE_OBJCOPY      $ENV{RPI_CC}/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-objcopy)
SET(CMAKE_OBJDUMP      $ENV{RPI_CC}/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-objdump)
SET(CMAKE_STRIP        $ENV{RPI_CC}/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-strip)
SET(CMAKE_RANLIB       $ENV{RPI_CC}/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-tanlib)

# where is the target environment 
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  $ENV{RPI_CC}/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi)

# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

(2) When I run cmake at command window at Windows7, it is compiling for Visual Studio 10 in default (I don't choose any option and it happens in default) as `-- Building for: Visual Studio 10`. How can I change it to build for Debian Linux?
Thanks

Comment: There is a "-G" option which allows you to specify the generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(According to the documentation at http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling)

You need a [toolchain file](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#The_toolchain_file), and you must instruct CMake to use it, by defining the CMake variable `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`.

What is more, if you want to build using that toolchain, your CMake generator must be "Unix Makefile". That means that the build tool will be `make` instead of Visual Studio. Because I am unsure that CMake can make a Visual Studio project that uses the gcc cross-compiler.

Comment: Yes toolchain-rpi.cmake is my tool chaing file. Thanks

Comment: @batuman Do you manage to make CMake use by defining the variable `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`?

Comment: Yes I did. I made a build folder inside the project folder. Then I types as user:> cmake -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../toolchain-rpi.cmake ../. Then the cmake shows -- Building for: Visual Studio 10. But I like to build for ARM. Then if I use CMake-GUI, which generator I have to use?

Comment: @batuman I have modified my answer, to tell which generator to use. Once my post answers all your questions, please accept it, to close the question and reward my answer.

Comment: But let me clarify some. I use CMake-GUI and the same toolchain-rpi.cmake file as shown above. Then at GUI, I chose Visual Studio 10 at Specify the generator for this project, then it works. Why I need to choose Visual Studio 10?

Comment: Do you really need to choose Visual Studio 10? What if you choose "Unix Makefile" as generator in CMake-GUI?

Comment: If I choose "Unix Makefile", it is linking to my Matlab/bin and got error. The error is "It fails with the following output:
   Change Dir: C:/ThitSan_Backup/RasberryPI/userland-   master/host_applications/linux/apps/mStream/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
  Run Build Command:C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2008b/bin/win32/gmake.exe