# CMake Cross Compilation always build for Visual Studio 10

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I have [a similar query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856544/makefile-generator-specification-at-cross-compilation-with-cmake) and close it as I thought it worked. Actually I still have problem. So I post in a new thread. My CMake is always building for Visual Studio 2010. I am cross compiling for Raspberry PI and my toolchain file is as follow.

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux) # this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)  # this one not so much

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   C:/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER C:/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)
SET(CMAKE_AR           C:/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar)
SET(CMAKE_LINKER       C:/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld)
SET(CMAKE_NM           C:/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-nm)
SET(CMAKE_OBJCOPY      C:/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy)
SET(CMAKE_OBJDUMP      C:/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump)
SET(CMAKE_STRIP       C:/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip)
SET(CMAKE_RANLIB       C:/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-tanlib)

# where is the target environment 
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  C:/ThitSan_Backup/RasberryPI/rpi/helloWorld)

# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

But when I run cmake, it build for Visual Studio 2010 as shown in the attached image.[image]
Both `cmake -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../toolchain-rpi.cmake ../` and `cmake  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../toolchain-rpi.cmake ../`gave me same results.
My question are
(1) why cmake is trying to build for Visual Studio 2010 in default?
(2)What are the things I need to look at to cross compile for Raspberry PI using arm compiler to avoid such problem?
Thanks

Comment: Try removing the space after the `-D` (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17181954/2556117) for further info).

Comment: I think, still the same. Let me try tonight.

Comment: I am sorry the initial question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856544/makefile-generator-specification-at-cross-compilation-with-cmake was not satisfactory.

You could have unaccepted my answer, and edit your question to make it more precise. That would have been perfectly fine.

Comment: @lrineau Many thanks. I edited my query to be more specific for what I like to know.

Comment: @lrineau I am in Windows 7 OS and I set the environment Path to C:\arm-bcm2708\gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian\bin. But when I test it at command window as arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v. It is complained as "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" is not recognized. I think this is the problem.

Comment: Once you have the solution, I suggest you write an official "answer" post, and then self-accept it.

Comment: I set to the path for the bin folder, don't know why "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" is not recognized.

Comment: According to this discussion (http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=4058), there is no way to cross compile from Windows for Raspberry PI.That is the solution. I have to find Linux OS. Actually there is a way, but not straight forward.

Comment: That is why Cmake is always building for Visual Studio 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed all the instructions and discussions in this [link](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling). But Arm Cross Compiler for the RPI is just for the Linux OS. So my solution for that is I installed Oracle's VirtualBox. Then implement all cross-compile in that OS.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to run cmake on windows without generating Visual Studio project. The solution is to install MinGW on Windows, and then use the following command to generate Makefiles:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../toolchain-rpi.cmake ..
```

Finally, file named Makefile is generated instead of Visual Studio project. Please be sure there is no other sh.exe in your PATH env variable.