# How to generate Makefile for mingw32 using CMake

Tags: makefile, cmake, generator, mingw32

I have a QT Application and I am using CMake for building the project.
I want to compile the same code using mingw32 into windows binaries.

When I run CMake it shows that I don't have "MinGW Makefiles" generator. I don't see any place from where to install these generators. How can I install these generators ?

Comment: Did you adapt your `toolchain.cmake` file appropriately to point to your local installation of `MinGW GCC`?

Comment: May be the information [given here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856544/makefile-generator-specification-at-cross-compilation-with-cmake) helps you a bit.